# Why stackoverflow's website is not optimized to big screen?

Tags: feature-request, design

It is really annoying that stackoverflow's website is not optimized to big screen - my screen is 29 inch wide - all the left and right side is unused, empty, and in the same time question / answer textfield / view is small, can not see long code lines. You can see the overall look down here:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The center component is often narrower than I would like on a wide screen, even if I would not want it to be the full width of the screen. It would be **much** better if it were in a frame with draggabble edges so that each user could make it as wide or as narrow as suits them and their screen.

Comment: Closely related on Meta.SE: [Utilizing blank space](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210995/utilising-blank-space)

Comment: Why is this downvoted so much?! On a 27" screen, the content's width is VERY VERY small! And even for creating a GreaseMonkey script I had to fiddle a lot with absolute pixels instead of percentages. Why are the values so hardcoded?

Answer (score 8):

While wider lines would be useful for some code (usually overly long lines indicate bad code unless it's a big string literal e.g. for a log message), they make normal text incredibly hard to read. So I don't think it makes lots of sense to make the page much wider.

Comment: agree, but at least that white space would be used for something

Comment: @János no, the space on the sides should not be used *for anything*. You want to draw attention to the center, not have users be distracted by non-relevant items on the sides.

Comment: Yeah, nothing worse than ads etc. in that white space outside...

Comment: I think if Steve Jobs would be your boss, he would not hesitate to fire you, because screen is designed to show something, and not show the emptiness .. it is not about advertisement .. put something there, allign the whole freaking website differently, but I do not want to see white empty spaces

Comment: @János see http://store.apple.com/us - yeah, I guess Steve Jobs would have made the space grey instead. Anyways, if you have an awesome idea for a specific "something" that should be put there, feel free to propose it; otherwise, enjoy your blank space like everyone else does. But keep in mind there's already people who want to hide the "hot meta posts" box, so I don't think adding even more content to the site will find a huge following.

Comment: I don't see the harm in resizing the width of the main text area if the browser window is wide enough to leave empty space otherwise. Nobody would be forced to make their browser window wider if they don't like long text lines. If the sidebars have a fixed width, and the rest of the window is used for the main text area, everybody can resize their browser to make the text as wide or narrow as they like.

Comment: @RetoKoradi that would be an extremely bad idea - practically, you would force users to use their browser window for SO _and nothing else_. I have many tabs open, some of them need a wide window. But I also want the SO text to be considerably smaller than my 24" monitor size. Implementing your suggestion would force me to use a second, smaller browser window for SO. And you don't even consider that not everybody uses a stacking window manager, it would be even more annoying with the tiling window manager I use at work...

Comment: @l4mpi: Good point. I'm not using any web sites that require a wide window, but I can see how that would be a problem if you do. I could argue that having to scroll left and right to read **each line** if people post code with long lines is worse. But an ideal solution would work for all these use cases.

Comment: The ideal solution for overly long code would be a small button somewhere that stretches the code block over the full screen width while leaving anything else as it is.

Comment: I hate to scrolldown the screen too much, I preffer to read everything in one wider screen than moving the text up and down and remembering the code. I usually have to copy paste some SO codes to Notepad++ and read it better there.

Comment: Of course, we talk about Themes - we don't ask to spend 100s of hours. Why do you want to decide that a user must use narrow columns if he prefers wider columns?

Answer (score 4):

[ThiefMaster points out one very practical reason to avoid this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266204/why-stackoverflows-website-is-not-optimized-to-big-screen/266206#266206); here's another: right now, if you format your code so that it looks good on *your* screen, it'll look pretty much the same on anyone else's. Maybe a few characters wider or narrower if you're unlucky in the font department, but pretty close.

Whereas if you format your code for your screen, chances are it'll look awful on mine, where I keep the window at half-width to leave room for other things (like editors...) on the rest of the screen.

Chances are, you're using a whitespace agnostic language anyway; just wrap the long lines and your readers will thank you.

Comment: I am developing in Xcode, how is it possible that either in big, wide window or in small, narrow window source-code looks good?

Comment: Easy - just get rid of the space-wasting sidebars in XCode.

Comment: On Stackoverflow, a lot of code is cut because the lines are too long. But this is not the subject of this proposal: If users like to better use the Monitor space by changing to a wide Stackoverflow-Theme, then it is and it should be their decision.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is user experience / readability.

StackExchange is so vast by now, it can answer this very question in itself:

https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/108803/101037

To address your specific arguments:

- Parse Server Dashboard does not use "all the space", the empty space is just in between and information more scattered across the screen. This makes information such as the table in your screenshot harder to read, because your eyes need to scan the lines.
- "Ugly" / "Tasteful" are is a subjective evaluations. You may as well ask why the site is called `StackOverflow` and not `BufferOverflow`.