# Wider column for code: Possible?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

Code seems to be the most important aspect of the majority of SO questions and answers.

Good code examples often involve elaborate and descriptive symbol naming to best convey the purpose, meaning and context. This greatly reduces the need for comments, boilerplate and larger insight into a project as container, all rapidly increasing understanding and reducing reading and digestion time.

Unfortunately this often creates slightly longer lines of code than might be within a normal, real world project.

As a result, many lines wind up scrolling horizontally in SO code views. This is a horrid experience and, so far as I can see, made worse by the narrowness of the column for code.

Would it be a great trouble to widen the code windows/boxes within the SO layout to accomodate a full width (of SO's layout) code view, so as to give a better code reading experience?

The easiest way to do this might be simply splitting the right column wherever it comes in contact with a code view. Something like this:

---

| Descriptive stuff is this wide, as currently are, with verbiage | *Right column here (**jobs etc**)* |

```
| Code "rows" views are full width of SO, extending and going right through  |
```

Comment: Code is already too wide for smaller screen... I don't think we need wider code for desktop either

Comment: For which the obvious response is: why can't the use of adaptive/responsive sizing be a good solution so all screen sizes might get the most out of SO?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300408/2675154, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266204/2675154

Comment: @confused one does not simply convert a high velocity site to a responsive design, that's a massive undertaking. Nonetheless: do want.

Comment: I get that it's not a small undertaking, @Gimby, but it's gotta be a lot less effort and much more instantly rewarding (to all screen sizes of the present and future) than the current efforts with SO.docs ;)

Comment: Eons ago I reviewed this StackApp/Userscript, looks like it's still working good: [Click to expand code regions](https://stackapps.com/q/2574/10590)